How can i create a save/delete button in Jetpack compose?
im new to Jetpack and the whole Android development.
My issue is that I have a @Composable like this:
@Composable
private fun RecipeDetailsBody(
  recipe: SmallResult,
  pressOnBack: () -> Unit,
  viewModel: DetailViewModel,
) {
  var like = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  LaunchedEffect(like.value) {
    if(viewModel.checkIfRecipeIsFavourite(recipe.id) > 0) {
      like.value = true
    }
    if(like.value) {
      viewModel.saveRecipe(recipe.convertToFavourite())
    } else {
      viewModel.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)
    }
  }

  Column(
    modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxSize()
      .background(White)
      .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
  ) {
    Row(
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
      horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
      Column(
        modifier = Modifier
          .weight(0.8f)
      ) {
        Text(
          text = recipe.name,
          style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
          fontWeight = FontWeight.Black,
          overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
          maxLines = 3,
          modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp, top = 0.dp)
        )
      }
      Box(
        modifier = Modifier
          .weight(0.2f)
          .padding(8.dp)
          .widthIn(max = 0.1.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

      ) {
        Button(
          interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource(),
          onClick = {
            like.value = !like.value
          }
        ) {
          val tint = if(like.value) TealLight else Grey
          Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ThumbUp,
            contentDescription = "Add To Favourites",
            tint = TealLight,
            modifier = Modifier
              .size(40.dp)
              .padding(4.dp),
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


My problem is that when I press the like button, it recomposes this part, and the like stays true forever. I have no idea how to properly set up this button press.
My main goal would be if i press the button when its grey and the item is not saved, save it and make the button colored. When its colored and pressed again, remove it from the db.
When I open this page, i want to check if the recipe is already saved and pre color the button.
I use LaunchedEffect because my db function is supend. But if there is a better way to make this happen im all ears!

From what I can understand from your problem description and code you provided, I think your problem is below:
 LaunchedEffect(like.value) {
    if(viewModel.checkIfRecipeIsFavourite(recipe.id) > 0) {
        like.value = true
    }
    if(like.value) {
        viewModel.saveRecipe(recipe.convertToFavourite())
    } else {
        viewModel.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)
    }
}

The launchEffect only runs when the value of like is changed, so you are basically not getting the value of .checkIfRecipeIsFavourite() during initial composition.
What you can do instead is, check if the recipe is already in fav during initial composition like this:
 LaunchedEffect(true) {
    like = viewModel.checkIfRecipeIsFavourite(recipe.id) > 0
}

Then move your saving/deleting logic to another launched effect:
  LaunchedEffect(like.value) {
    if (like.value) {
        viewModel.saveRecipe(recipe.convertToFavourite())
    } else {
        viewModel.deleteRecipe(recipe.id)
    }
}

Hope this helps.
